# Pytables slow on query for non-matching string

Tags: python, pytables

I'm relatively new in python and I'm using pytables to store some genomic annotations in hdf for faster query. I find querying a non-matching string in the table is slow, but I'm unsure how to optimize it for better performance.

Below shown is one of the tables:

```
In [5]: t
Out[5]: 
/gene/annotation (Table(315202,), fletcher32, blosc(5)) ''
  description := {
  "name": StringCol(itemsize=36, shape=(), dflt='', pos=0),
  "track": StringCol(itemsize=12, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1),
  "etype": StringCol(itemsize=12, shape=(), dflt='', pos=2),
  "event": StringCol(itemsize=36, shape=(), dflt='', pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'irrelevant'
  chunkshape := (1365,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "name": Index(9, full, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=True}
```

When a condition matches something in the table, timeit returns in the microseconds.

```
In [6]: timeit [x for x in t.where("name == 'record_exists_in_table'")]
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop
```

However, when I tried searching for a non-existence string, it is in the milliseconds.

```
In [8]: timeit [x for x in t.where("name == 'no_such_record'")]
10 loops, best of 3: 56 ms per loop
```

Any advice that points me toward the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  Could you please file a ticket in the PyTables github repo?  If you can add a self-contained example, that would be great.  I'd like to have a look at that.

Comment: Just in case your problem is the same as mine:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197622/pandas-hdfstore-slow-on-query-for-non-matching-string/

Comment: @Francesc I can confirm this regression in 3.1.1. Downgrade to 3.0.0 resolves the issue. The link to appropriate github issue with code to reproduce is: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/390

Answer (score 0):

I've exhausted my search on the web and yet to find anything that resolves the issue. So I've decided to use `SeqIO.index_db()` in biopython to create a separate index, then a check to make sure a condition will be found before executing a pytable query. Not exactly the pretty solution I was looking for, but this will do. It has substantially improved the performance on non-matching condition.

```
In [6]: timeit [x for x in t.where("name == 'not_found_in_table'")]
10 loops, best of 3: 51.6 ms per loop

In [9]: timeit [x for x in t.search_by_gene('not_found_in_table')]
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 µs per loop
```