# Pandas HDFStore: slow on query for non-matching string

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

My issue is that when I try to look for a string that is NOT contained in the DataFrame (which is stored in an hdf5 file), it takes a very long time to complete the query. For example:

I have a df that contains 2*10^9 rows. It is stored in an HDF5 file. I have a string column named "code", that was marked as "data_column" (therefore it is indexed).

When I search for a code that exists in the dataset ( store.select('df', 'code=valid_code') ) it takes around 10 seconds to get 70K rows.

However, when I search for a code that does NOT exist in the dataset ( store.select('df', 'code=not_valid_code') ) it takes around 980 seconds to get the result of the query (0 rows).

I create the store like: 
store = pd.HDFStore('data.h5', complevel=1, complib='zlib')
And the first append is like:
store.append('df', chunk, data_columns=['code'], expectedrows=2318185498)

Is this behavior normal or is there something wrong going on?

Thanks!

PS: this question is probably related with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386146/pytables-slow-on-query-for-non-matching-string)

**UPDATE:**

Following Jeff's advice, I replicated his experiment, and I got the following results on a Mac. This is the table that was generated:

```
!ptdump -av test.h5
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/df (Group) ''
  /df._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['A'],
    encoding := None,
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {1: {'type': 'Index', 'names': [None]}, 'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['A'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['A']]
/df/table (Table(50000000,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "A": StringCol(itemsize=8, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (8192,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "A": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 11 attributes:
   [A_dtype := 'string64',
    A_kind := ['A'],
    CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := '',
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'A',
    NROWS := 50000000,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer']
```

And these are the results:

```
In [8]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 277 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 391 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
1 loops, best of 3: 533 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib2.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
1 loops, best of 3: 504 ms per loop
```

Since the differences were maybe not big enough, I tried the same experiment but with a bigger dataframe. Also, I did this experiment on a different machine, one with Linux.

This is the code (I just multiplied the original dataset by 10):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [ 'foo%05d' % i for i in range(500000) ]})

df = pd.concat([ df ] * 20)

store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

for i in range(50):
    print "%s" % i
    store.append('df',df,data_columns=['A'])
```

This is the table:

```
!ptdump -av test.h5
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/df (Group) ''
  /df._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['A'],
    encoding := None,
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {1: {'type': 'Index', 'names': [None]}, 'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['A'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['A']]
/df/table (Table(500000000,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "A": StringCol(itemsize=9, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (15420,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "A": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 11 attributes:
   [A_dtype := 'string72',
    A_kind := ['A'],
    CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := '',
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'A',
    NROWS := 500000000,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer']
```

These are the files:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 8.2G Oct  5 14:00 test.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 9.9G Oct  5 14:30 test_zlib.h5
```

And these are the results:

```
In [9]:%timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop

In [10]:%timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 980 ms per loop

In [11]:%timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
1 loops, best of 3: 7.02 s per loop

In [12]:%timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
1 loops, best of 3: 7.27 s per loop
```

These are my versions of Pandas and Pytables:

```
user@host:~/$ pip show tables
---
Name: tables
Version: 3.1.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 

user@host:~/$ pip show pandas
---
Name: pandas
Version: 0.14.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, pytz, numpy
```

Although I am quite sure that the issue is not related with Pandas, since I have observed similar behavior when using only Pytables without Pandas.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have switched to Pytables 3.0.0 and the problem got fixed. This is using the same files that were generated with Pytables 3.1.1.

```
In [4]:%timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
1 loops, best of 3: 205 ms per loop

In [4]:%timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop
```

Comment: can u show df.info() and pandas/pytables versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff's help I fixed the issue by downgrading Pytables to the version 3.0.0. The issue has been reported to the devs of Pytables.

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is one which we filed a bug a while ago [here](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/319) with the PyTables guys. Essentially, when using a compressed store AND specifying expectedrows AND using an indexed columns causes mis-indexing.

The soln is simply NOT to use expectedrows, and rather to ptrepack the file with a specified chunkshape (or AUTO). This is good practice anyhow. Further, not sure if you specifying compression up-front, but it is IMHO better to do this via ptrepack, see docs [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#compression). Their is also an issue on SO about this (can't find it right now, essentially if you are creating the file, don't don't index up-front but when you are done appending, if you can).

In any event, creating a test store:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'A' : [ 'foo%05d' % i for i in range(50000) ]})

In [2]: df = pd.concat([ df ] * 20)
```

Append 50M rows.

```
In [4]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [6]: for i in range(50):
   ...:     print "%s" % i
   ...:     store.append('df',df,data_columns=['A'])
   ...:
```

Here is the table

```
In [9]: !ptdump -av test.h5
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/df (Group) ''
  /df._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['A'],
    encoding := None,
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {1: {'type': 'Index', 'names': [None]}, 'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['A'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['A']]
/df/table (Table(50000000,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "A": StringCol(itemsize=8, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (8192,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "A": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 11 attributes:
   [A_dtype := 'string64',
    A_kind := ['A'],
    CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := '',
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'A',
    NROWS := 50000000,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer']
```

Create a blosc and zlib version.

```
In [12]: !ptrepack --complib blosc --chunkshape auto --propindexes test.h5 test_blosc.h5

In [13]: !ptrepack --complib zlib --chunkshape auto --propindexes test.h5 test_zlib.h5

In [14]: !ls -ltr *.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jreback users 866182540 Oct  4 20:31 test.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jreback users 976674013 Oct  4 20:36 test_blosc.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jreback users 976674013 Oct  4  2014 test_zlib.h5
```

Perf is pretty similar (for the found rows)

```
In [10]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 337 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test_blosc.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 345 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib.h5','df',where='A = "foo00002"')
1 loops, best of 3: 347 ms per loop
```

And missing rows (though the compressed do perform better here).

```
In [11]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
10 loops, best of 3: 82.4 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test_blosc.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
10 loops, best of 3: 32.2 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit pd.read_hdf('test_zlib.h5','df',where='A = "bar"')
10 loops, best of 3: 32.3 ms per loop
```

So. try w/o the expected rows specifier, and use ptrepack.

Another possiblity if you are expecting a relatively low density of entries for this column (e.g. a smaller number of unique entries). Is to select the entire column, `store.select_column('df','A').unique()` in this case, and use that as a quick lookup mechanism (so you don't search at all).

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help, this issue is driving my crazy. I just replicated your experiments and updated the post with the results. What version of Pytables are you using? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: this is with PyTables 3.0.0, but 3.1.1 and should be the same (and pandas master), but 0.14.1 should be the same as well.

Comment: I switched to Pytables 3.0.0 and the problem is solved. I will report this to the devs of Pytables. Thanks!

Comment: interesting, so a regression in 3.1.1. ok then.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for pointing this out in a comment to my (separate) question. In my case it is not an `expectedrows` issue but an apparent regression in pytables 3.1.1 concerning indexing of StringCols. I found the OP's github issue. Just in case you are interested: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/390